# Is array indexing costly?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In the snippet below from [backbone](http://backbonejs.org/), this line

```
(ev = events[i]).callback.call(ev.ctx);
```

is not clear.  I would like to assume that `ev = events[i]` is interpreted before `ev.ctx` as the variable seems to have no other purpose except to reduce array indexing.

Assuming this is correct, is this done because array indexing is costly?  I know in embedded engineering array indexing is costly when you are working with limited resources.  But I thought this was not such a concern in JavaScript.

**Backbone Snippet**

```
triggerEvents = function(events, args) {
    var ev, 
        i = -1, 
        l = events.length;
    switch (args.length) {
        case 0: 
            while (++i < l) {
                (ev = events[i]).callback.call(ev.ctx);
            }
            return;
        case 1: 
            while (++i < l) {
               (ev = events[i]).callback.call(ev.ctx, args[0]);
            }
            return;
        case 2: 
            while (++i < l) { 
                (ev = events[i]).callback.call(ev.ctx, args[0], args[1]);
            }
            return;
        case 3: 
            while (++i < l) { 
                (ev = events[i]).callback.call(ev.ctx, args[0], args[1], args[2]);
            }
            return;
        default: 
            while (++i < l) {
                (ev = events[i]).callback.apply(ev.ctx, args);
            }
    }
};
```

Comment: This feels like over engineering.  You are still performing an array look-up and variable assignment.  Is there some garbage collection side benefit or cleverness related to array out of bounds that I don't understand?

Comment: This is how they describe it: http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-17

Comment: I don't think there's an arcane garbage collection trick here. Can't we just use Occam's razor and assume that keeping the iterated element labelled is good practice?

Comment: I dont have a clear idea, but is it possible that by the time the callback function has been called it will use the updated value of i if events[i] was used instead of ev?

Comment: I don't understand the whole switch statement anyway. Why not always use `.apply`? Accessing a variable is certainly faster than accessing an array, but whether it has an impact on the overall performance is a different question.

Comment: @FelixKling, check out my answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968387/backbone-triggerevents-variable/14968728#14968728. In short: yes, `Function.call` is faster. And yes, I would say, `Backbone.Events` is one of the few places where I would say it matters, because the syncronous eventing is at the core of so many Backbone operations.

Comment: Caching the array lookup into a variable so you don't have to do it again is quicker.  Also, see this commit: https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/commit/103c9e87e46f94f87735fcea37b8456ae0f8f299

Comment: ?? that optimization per the jsperf is not acutally in the development code? why is that? ... http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK using the [treehugger.js demo](http://ajaxorg.github.com/treehugger/test.html) to generate an [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) of the backbone.js approach with this simplified bit of code:

```
var ev, i = -1, l = 3;
while (++i < l) { 
  (ev = events[i]).callback.call(ev.ctx, args[0], args[1], args[2]);
}
```

Produces this AST:

```
[
  VarDecls(
      [
        VarDecl("ev"),
        VarDeclInit(
            "i",
            PrefixOp(
                "-",
                Num("1")
            )
        ),
        VarDeclInit(
            "l",
            Num("3")
        )
      ]
  ),
  While(
      Op(
          "<",
          PrefixOp(
              "++",
              Var("i")
          ),
          Var("l")
      ),
      Block(
          [
            Call(
                PropAccess(
                    PropAccess(
                        Assign(
                            Var("ev"),
                            Index(
                                Var("events"),
                                Var("i")
                            )
                        ),
                        "callback"
                    ),
                    "call"
                ),
                [
                  PropAccess(
                      Var("ev"),
                      "ctx"
                  ),
                  Index(
                      Var("args"),
                      Num("0")
                  ),
                  Index(
                      Var("args"),
                      Num("1")
                  ),
                  Index(
                      Var("args"),
                      Num("2")
                  )
                ]
            )
          ]
      )
  )
]
```

While the implied "cleaner" approach:

```
var ev, i = -1, l = 3;
while (++i < l) {
  ev = events[i];
  ev.callback.call(ev.ctx, args[0], args[1], args[2]);
}
```

Produces this AST:

```
[
  VarDecls(
      [
        VarDecl("ev"),
        VarDeclInit(
            "i",
            PrefixOp(
                "-",
                Num("1")
            )
        ),
        VarDeclInit(
            "l",
            Num("3")
        )
      ]
  ),
  While(
      Op(
          "<",
          PrefixOp(
              "++",
              Var("i")
          ),
          Var("l")
      ),
      Block(
          [
            Assign(
                Var("ev"),
                Index(
                    Var("events"),
                    Var("i")
                )
            ),
            Call(
                PropAccess(
                    PropAccess(
                        Var("ev"),
                        "callback"
                    ),
                    "call"
                ),
                [
                  PropAccess(
                      Var("ev"),
                      "ctx"
                  ),
                  Index(
                      Var("args"),
                      Num("0")
                  ),
                  Index(
                      Var("args"),
                      Num("1")
                  ),
                  Index(
                      Var("args"),
                      Num("2")
                  )
                ]
            )
          ]
      )
  )
]
```

The only difference between these two is the `Assign()` takes place inside the `PropAccess()` while in the "cleaner" approach has it outside.  They have the same number of steps.  You could avoid the `Assign` all together and swap it with a second `Index`.  I'm afraid I don't know enough about JS internals to know if this is faster.  I would guess it is platform dependent.

Comment: Sure.  It's an Abstract Syntax Tree.  It represents each literal operation taken by a block of source code.  By being abstract it is not about a specific language.  In this case it is a convenient way to de-compile JavaScript to see if a specific approach is more efficient.  Unfortunately in this case it seems to just point back to your original question, and leaves me asking it as well.

Comment: Well Treehugger.js is a tool that produces this by reading the JavaScript as a string, but JavaScript engines do something like this when they compile JavaScript.

Comment: @pure_code, I see your point. I was hoping to see (with AST) an op code difference, but in fact the analysis revealed that there isn't a difference (both have one index look-up and one assignment).  I think fencliff's comment shows that the only real optimization is using `call` instead of `apply` which you have in your answer as well.