# Backbone triggerEvents variable

Tags: javascript, performance, backbone.js

I'm reading through the Backbone.js source and am confused by this

```
var triggerEvents = function(events, args) {
  var ev, i = -1, l = events.length;
  switch (args.length) {
    case 0: while (++i < l) (ev = events[i]).callback.call(ev.ctx);
    return;
    case 1: while (++i < l) (ev = events[i]).callback.call(ev.ctx, args[0]);
    return;
    case 2: while (++i < l) (ev = events[i]).callback.call(ev.ctx, args[0], args[1]);
    return;
    case 3: while (++i < l) (ev = events[i]).callback.call(ev.ctx, args[0], args[1], args[2]);
    return;
    default: while (++i < l) (ev = events[i]).callback.apply(ev.ctx, args);
  }
};
```

I have a number of questions-

1. Why is this an optimization for triggering events(as the annotated source says)?
2. What is ev.ctx?
3. What is .callback()?

This structure implies that if given the chance one should always use call as opposed to apply in the interests of speed, as the structure of this function seems to say "If I know how many args there are use call, instead, use apply", when one could just use apply all the way through.

In short I'm not sure what the purpose of this function is and why it has been written the way it has been written and if someone could tell me it would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a small [JSPerf test suite](http://jsperf.com/js-function-call-vs-function-apply) that compares `Function.call` and `Function.apply` performance. It shows quite clearly that (with Chrome 24) `Function.call` is faster by 30-50%. Try and run it in your browser to see how the performance differs.

This doesn't mean, however, that you should follow this optimization in your own code. The Backbone events functionality is at the core of Backbone, and a **lot** of events are fired. The authors have optimized this piece of code to squeeze the last bits of performance out of it. In most other cases this would be an over-optimization.

The `ev.callback` property is the callback function for the event.

Consider the following example:

```
this.model.on('change', this.handleChange, this);
```

The callback in this case is the `this.handleChange` method.

The notation `(ev = events[i]).callback.call` is just a shortcut for

```
ev = events[i];
ev.callback.call
```

The shortcut works, because in javascript an assignment operation returns the assigned value.

The `ev.ctx` property on the other hand is the object to bind as the `this` context to the callback function. `Backbone.Events.on` takes the context as an optional argument. In the above example the last argument, `this`, specifies that the callback function's context should be the containing class.